# What is the correct way to catch my exception originated from in my class and display it to over the main form?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

For example :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Do(string str)
    {
        try
        {
            int num = int.Parse(str);
            return num;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And from the main form:

```
MyClass class = new MyClass();
int num = class.Do("123");
```

Is it OK to replace

```
throw new Exception(ex.Message)
```

with

```
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
```

or

```
throw `MessageBox`
```

only from the main form ?

Comment: Why do you create a new exception from the caught one? This removes your stacktrace.

Comment: That's why i asked...

Comment: Why not use int.TryParse instead of int.Parse - and avoid exceptions altogether?

Comment: This is only example, my question is what is the correct way to use exceptions...

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz That could potentially be worse, because then he needs to have every single method between this one and his UI layer returning some boolean indicating that the input couldn't be parsed.  The best option would probably be to use a UI control that doesn't *allow* non-numeric input, but if that's not an option, I'd actually prefer an exception in this case, simply because this code isn't capable of handling the "is not a number" case.

Comment: @Servy - the comment was about using exception when it isn't necessary. Does a specific string being non-numeric an exceptional condition? Probably not.. therefore, it shouldn't be an exception.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz In this case it may well be an exceptional case because the code that is parsing the string is not capable of resolving the problem.  Exceptions are a useful tool, and this is using them to solve the exact problem that they were designed to do.  What you are describing is essentially attempting to use an error-code based style of programming in which every single method returns a value indicating if it was successful or not.  In the general case, that causes a *lot* of problems.

Comment: @Servy, being the code able to resolve the problem, or not - is irrelevant to the question of "Is exception a right tool for...?". It is relevant to the question "does the code designed correctly to solve the problem?"  Exceptions are for notifying and handling exceptional conditions.. Now, a string being non-numeric is exceptional, if it retrieved from an API which suppose to return a numeric string. It is not exceptional when the string is provided by the user. I would argue that the later is much more common

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz As I said before, in a well designed app the UI should not be providing such an invalid string to the business layer in the first place.  *That* is the real problem.  The fact remains that, for the business layer, having a non-numeric string here is an unrecoverable problem.  When faced with an unrecoverable problem, the best thing to do is throw an exception.  If someone up the call chain knows how to recover from the problem, they can do so.  Failing to parse a string isn't universally non-exceptional behavior.  *In this context* it is.

Comment: Something else that makes this exceptional is that a UI will perform basic input validation on its own.  It is reasonable for the business layer to treat invalid input as an exceptional circumstance.  If the UI failed its task at validation, there is nothing the business layer can do but tell the UI to handle the situation.

Comment: @Servy who said it is a business layer? Maybe it is a view-model... maybe the business layer would accept an number in the first place, because it has nothing to do with parsing numeric strings (maybe)... maybe the code is just an example to explain the question (actually - not maybe). I wrote my first comment because `int.Parse` is a red flag of misused exception. But here it's just an example for a code that throws... What that code is - we do not know

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz The type has no use of, or references to, anything UI related, which is a pretty strong indication that it's not UI code.

Comment: Tip: You can add additional data to your exception before you throw it. Using `Exception.Data.Add` you can add key/value pairs to the exception. I've used it when performing complicated validation on telephone numbers so that I can return a key of "UIMessage" and a value that is suitable for display to a user, e.g. "Area code 911 is, with all due respect, not permitted.". If the application using the class has a UI, it can check in a catch for a "UIMessage" to display.

Comment: @Servy - You are so right! The type is real production type, with the real-life name "MyClass"... It is an obvious indication that this code is more than an example of what the OP is asking about...

Answer (score 4):

`MyClass` is a class designed to handle the business logic of your application.  It is not there to interact with the user interface.  When it encounters a problem that it can't solve, it should be throwing an exception, not trying to display an error message to the user.

Eventually that exception will bubble up to the UI layer of your application.  It is within that layer of your application that you can catch the relevant exception, inform the user of a problem, and consider how to move forward.  In the case of a non-numeric string, that might mean prompting for a new value.  In the case of something more serious, it may mean informing them that your program needs to shut down, or any number of options in between.

Comment: @EricJ. Probably [someone imagining that exceptions shouldn't be used at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550141/what-is-the-correct-way-to-catch-my-exception-originated-from-in-my-class-and-di/23550213?noredirect=1#comment36133204_23550141) seems more likely than just revenge downvotes. While we both disagree with that position, it *is* an understandable position to take, and an entirely acceptable reason to downvote the posts. It's a risk that comes along with the more subjective "how should I design this" questions rather than a more objective, "how to make this compile" questions.

Comment: @EricJ. I'm an optimist I guess, and simply hope that the downvotes were because someone (or two someones) didn't like the design.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot do something useful with an Exception at a given tier of code, let it propagate up to a layer of code that can do something useful with it.

In this case, you want your UI to do something useful.  Let the UI catch the Exception, and display the desired message as a result.

Answer (score -1):

This question is too wide because really there are many ways to handle exception but this

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
```

is not one of them.

if you in a win forms project you can do this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Do(string str)
    {
        try
        {
            int num = int.Parse(str);
            return num;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

If you have server code, you can do this

```
try
{
 ....
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Log your error to database, to event log, to file;
}
```

In a server application that communicates to client, one of the ways is this

```
public int Do(DoRequest request)
{
    var response = new DoResponse();
    try
    {
        response.num = int.Parse(request.str);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         // Log here;
         response.Error = ex.Message;                
    }
    return response;
}
```

And I am sure there are many other ways. One law you should follow - server code = server handling, UI code = UI handling

Comment: You should not be mixing the UI with the business logic by having a non-UI class responsible for displaying a UI to the user to indicate an error.  The UI layer should be responsible for that.

Comment: These are just examples of both sides. I don't know what you complaining about

Comment: I'm complaining about the fact that the OP is asking how to design his program, and you're giving him bad advice about how to design his program.

Comment: @Servy Your statement is incorrect. That is NOT what the OP originally asked. That was only what was later clarified in comments. As for "bad advice"...the three examples listed above are standard and idiomatic and involve actual code, which apparently isn't a bar your answer has to hurdle...

Comment: @JamesDevlin: The OP asked in the title of the question `What is the correct way to catch my exception originated from in my class and display it to over the main form?`  `MyClass` is clearly business layer, and displaying a message box from the business layer is poor design.

Comment: Indeed, and in the body of the question: "Is it OK to replace throw new Exception(ex.Message) with MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) or throw MessageBox only from the main form ?" along with a code example.

Comment: @ErikJ. It's not "clearly" anything of the sort. It could be a viewmodel class from MVVM. It could be a tightly coupled GUI class. You're correct that displaying a message box from the business layer is poor design, but my answer didn't do that, neither does the answer we are commenting on now. I put a ... to specifically indicate a switch of context between the two. Please read answers carefully before criticizing.

Comment: @Servy You need really to read what I wrote - "if you in a win forms project". Now, if someone writes business logic into WinForms - this is different problem

Comment: Even when writing a winforms application it is still important to separate out the UI layers from the business logic, and for the two to not intermingle.  They can be in the same project and still be kept conceptually separated.  Pulling your layers out into different assemblies is one way to further solidify the separation, but it is certainly not a requirement.

Comment: I think we're all on the same page here.

Comment: @Servy All you trying to do at this point is to protect the idea why you down-voted. But if I would say - "hey, if `MyClass` is `MyClass : Form`", would you be happier?

Comment: @T.S. That would still be mixing together the UI and business logic.  They should be clearly separated, rather than intermingled into one giant rats nest of code.  An answer indicating where to handle exceptions should be addressing that point by discussing when exceptions should be handled.  The question is about who should be responsible for reporting an error, which this question doesn't really answer, rather than the actual code perspective of how do I inform the user of an error, which the question indicates he already knows.